# Iterating an interface array with `forEach()`

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I'm new to Typescript and I'd like to save the response of an HTTP GET to an array of a type defined by an interface.

```js
getErrors() {
  return this.http.get<ErrorsInterface[]>(environment.apiUrl+'errors').toPromise()
}
```

Then I declare the array like this and call the function `getErrors()`

```js
errorsData: ErrorsInterface[]= []

this.errorsData = await this.ErrorsService.getErrors()
this.errorsData.forEach(res => {
 console.log(res.number)
})
```

But I receive the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.errorsData.forEach
> is not a function TypeError: this.errorsData.forEach is not a function

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need to convert the observable to a promise here. You could make do just with the observable

**Service**

```js
getErrors(): Observable<any> {  // <-- return observable
  return this.http.get<ErrorsInterface[]>(environment.apiUrl+'errors');
}
```

**Component**

```js
errorsData: ErrorsInterface[]= []

this.ErrorsService.getErrors().subscribe({
  next: (res: any) => {
    this.errorsData = res;
    this.errorsData.forEach(error => {
      console.log(error.number)
    });
  }
  error: (error: any) => {
    // handle error
  }
);
```

Note:

1. You cannot convert an asynchronous fetch to a synchronous one. Any statements (like the `forEach`) that depend on the async data *must* be inside the subscription. More info about async data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921).
2. `toPromise()` is [being deprecated](https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated) in RxJS 7 and might be gone in RxJS

Comment: thanks, i was also missing this this.errorsData = res.errors;

Answer (score 0):

```js
//in your service file

getErrors():Observable<ErrorInterface[]> {
      return this.http.get<ErrorsInterface[]>(environment.apiUrl+'errors')
  }
```

```js
 private errorsData= []


getErrors(){
this.ErrorsService.getErrors().Subscribe(res=> 
this.errorsData=res
)
//console.log(this.errorsData.length)
}
```

Comment: Why would you remove the type definition in the component? `errorsData: ErrorsInterface[]= []`?